# Querying JSON nested array object in SQL

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I have the following JSON and i need to query only the name property values.

```
DECLARE @j NVARCHAR(4000) = N'{  
   "ArrayValue":[
        {
            "name": "XXX",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "Memory123",
            "value": 20
        }
    ]
}'
```

Following is what i get with `OPENJSON()`

```
SELECT value as Name
FROM OPENJSON(@j, '$.ArrayValue')
```

Whcih will get the following output.

```
Name
---------------------------------------------------
{              "name": "Memory"          }
{              "name": "Memory123"          }
```

However I need the output in the following format.

```
Name
-----
Memory
Memory123
```

Is there any simpler way without using replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define ArrayValue as a JSON column, then use CROSS APPLY to get the name values. Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @j NVARCHAR(4000) = N'{  
   "ArrayValue":[
        {
            "name": "XXX",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "Memory123",
            "value": 20
        }
    ]
}'
SELECT b.name
FROM OPENJSON(@j)
WITH (ArrayValue NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) AS a
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.ArrayValue)
WITH ([name] NVARCHAR(100)) AS b
```